# Parity invariance of Einstein-Hilbert Lagrangian

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, parity

How can we show that the Einstein-Hilbert action is Parity invariant? $$
S_{EH}=\int \sqrt{-g}R d^4x $$

Comment: The Einstein-Hilbert action is a functional of the metric, so you need to (a) determine what the definition of a parity transformation of the metric is and (b) show that when the action is evaluated on the parity-transformed metric, it is equal to the action evaluated on the non-parity transformed metric.

Comment: I did not get why is $P(\sqrt{-g})=-\sqrt{-g}$

Comment: Just to clarify, when using the term "parity" here, are you referring to the spacetime transformation $x^0 \to x^0, \mathbf x \to -\mathbf x$ namely just parity in the spatial coordinates?

Comment: Yes, I get this $P(d^4 x)=-d^4x$, but the $\sqrt{-g}$?

Comment: I think  $\sqrt{-g}$ does not change, but the boundries are change also, If it is true, and so action  does not change.?